# Nomenclature of an organic compound

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

Which substituent should be placed first (in case of alphabetisation)?

1. **isopropyl-**
2. **methyl-**

I have come across two compounds: **1-methyl-3-methoxy-4-isopropylbenzene** and **1-isopropyl-4-methylcyclohexane**

So, is “iso” taken care of in case of alphabetisation? And, are there any special criteria for this operation?

Comment: The name “1-methyl-3-methoxy-4-isopropylbenzene” is not in accordance with IUPAC nomenclature. The systematic name is **1-isopropyl-2-methoxy-4-methylbenzene.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Note that the prefix ‘isopropyl’ is retained for use in general nomenclature but the preferred IUPAC name is ‘propan-2-yl’.)

Simple prefixes (simple substituent groups consisting of just one part that describes an atom, or group of atoms as a unit, for example methyl, methoxy, and isopropyl) are arranged alphabetically disregarding any multiplicative prefixes. Any multiplicative prefixes are inserted later and do not alter the alphabetical order.
For example, ‘1,2-dibromo-’ is considered to begin with ‘b’; ‘isopropyl’ is considered to begin with ‘i’.

On this matter, the current version of *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069-fp001)* reads as follows:

> **P-14.5** ALPHANUMERICAL ORDER
>
> Alphanumerical order has been commonly called ‘alphabetical order’. As these ordering principles do involve ordering both letters and numbers, in a strict sense, it is best called ‘alphanumerical order’ in order to convey the message that both letters and numbers are involved
>
> Alphanumerical order is used to establish the order of citation of detachable substituent prefixes (not the detachable saturation prefixes, hydro and dehydro), and the numbering of a chain, ring, or ring system when a choice is possible.
>
> (…)
>
> **P-14.5.1** Simple prefixes (i.e., those describing atoms and unsubstituted substituents) are arranged alphabetically; multiplicative prefixes, if necessary, are then inserted and do not alter the alphabetical order already established.

Therefore, the correct alphanumerical order in your first example corresponds to the name ***x*-isopropyl-*y*-methoxy-*z*-methylbenzene.**

In your second example, the correct alphanumerical order corresponds to the name ***x*-isopropyl-*y*-methylcyclohexane.**

Furthermore,

> **P-14.4** NUMBERING
>
> When several structural features appear in cyclic and acyclic compounds, low locants are assigned to them in the following decreasing order of seniority:
>
> (…)
>
> (f) detachable alphabetized prefixes, all considered together in a series of increasing numerical order;
>
> (g) lowest locants for the substituent cited first as a prefix in the name;
>
> (…)

Note that Rule f takes precedence over Rule g.

Therefore, your first example is named as **1-isopropyl-2-methoxy-4-methylbenzene** rather than 4-isopropyl-3-methoxy-1-methylbenzene since the locant set ‘1,2,4’ is lower than ‘1,3,4’.

[image: 1-isopropyl-2-methoxy-4-methylbenzene]

Your second example is named as **1-isopropyl-4-methylcyclohexane** rather than 4-isopropyl-1-methylcyclohexane since isopropyl is cited first as a prefix in the name.

[image: 1-isopropyl-4-methylcyclohexane]