# How to name this compound

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, hydrocarbons

2 bromo 3 methyl-butane or 3 bromo 2 methyl-butane. In general, if we have a symmetrical situation I know the functional groups should be ordered alphabetically and I also know that the smallest possible number on the functional group should be used. But what if each f-group is equidistant from the ends of the chain. Which one gets the smallest number?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/68624/alphabetization-rule-in-case-of-consecutively-placed-substituents

Comment: ok, does this take priority over alphabetical order then?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really sure what you mean. Alphanumeric order dictates that the name is of the form *x*-bromo-*y*-methylbutane. That's a given, and you didn't seem to have an issue with that. Your question is whether (*x*,*y*) should be (2,3) or (3,2). As described in the linked question, rule P-45.2.3 would lead to (2,3) being the preferred locant set. Quoting myself: "The correct way to do it is [...] first, order the prefixes by alphabetical order, and then choose the locant set in order to minimise the locants."

Comment: Also related: [Order of citation of alkyl and halide prefixes in IUPAC names](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/39928/7951)