# Priority among Halogens in Organic Nomenclature

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

I have been trying to learn IUPAC nomenclature during the past few days.

I have been using the MarvinSketch software to play around with random structures and its generated names and comparing them to my own results.
I stumbled across the following compound:

[image]

The nomenclature for the compound is shown as (1*Z*)‐1‐bromo‐2‐iodoethene

Is there any reason why (1*Z*)‐1‐iodo‐2‐bromoethene might be wrong? Is there a priority series among the halogens?

Comment: @orthocresol (1Z)‐1‐bromo‐2‐iodoethene is different from (1Z)‐1‐iodo‐2‐bromoethene and not just a rearrangement of prefixes since 1-bromo prefix is used in the first name and 2-bromo prefix is used in the second one.

Comment: Related: [Order of citation of alkyl and halide prefixes in IUPAC names](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/39928/101286)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have figured out the *Z* part of the nomenclature correctly. Now as to the question of why **1-bromo-2-iodo...** and not **1-iodo-2-bromo...**, we look at section P-14.4 (g) of the *Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry. IUPAC Recommendations
and Preferred Names 2013*, which states the following:

> P-14.4 NUMBERING
>
> When several structural features appear in cyclic and acyclic compounds, low locants are assigned to them in the
> following decreasing order of seniority:
>
> [...]
>
> (g) locants for the substituent cited first as a prefix in the name;

According to this rule, the priority in numbering depends upon where each prefix is present within the name. You cannot have **2-bromo-1-iodo...** or **2-iodo-1-bromo...** as a possible name when the substituents are simple substituents.

Now, how do we decide which comes first? Is it the bromine or iodine group? For this we look into section P-14.5 which deals with alphanumeric order and states:

> P-14.5 ALPHANUMERIC ORDER
>
> [...]
>
> **P-14.5.1** Simple prefixes (i.e., those describing atoms and unsubstituted substituents) are arranged alphabetically;
> multiplicative prefixes, if necessary, are then inserted and do not alter the alphabetical order already established.

Therefore, since bromo- comes first alphabetically, we place it first before iodine and by P-14.4 (g), the bromine gets priority.

Therefore, the PIN of the given compound becomes **(Z)-1-bromo-2-iodoethene**

[image]

Comment: For a PIN you need 1Z not just Z

Comment: Is it necessary. since the there can only be one location for the double bond to exist?

Comment: @SafdarFaisal Check P-14.3.3 of IUPAC Blue Book 2013, for a name to be a PIN, dropping of a locant like '1' is generally permissible if without ambiguity, it is not allowed in PIN.