# Alphabetical priority of the isopropyl group

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

This passage is contradictory. I've boxed the section that confused me.

[image]

Why would the book tell me to alphabetize substituents, only to clearly ignore its own rule about alphabetizing substituents?

Seems to me that "isopropyl" should come before "methyl," as the letter "i" is most definitely before the letter "m" in the alphabet. And the book makes no mention about ignoring the "iso-" prefix.

So:

1) Should methyl come before isopropyl?

2) If so, why?

Comment: Related: [Alphabetical order in nomenclature](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/46657/7951)

Answer (score 1):

**The iso prefix is included in the alphabetic order.**

For eg:- The compound Thymol has the following IUPAC name :- 2-Isopropyl-5-methylphenol and not 5-methyl-2-Isopropylphenol.

Therefore the name of your compound should be 4-isopropyl-2,3,3-trimethylheptane.