# The reason behind the alphabetical order in nomenclature

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

I hope my question is not too dumb but hey I am learning from the beginning

so when we have a compound such as 6-ethyl-3methylnonane, obvioysly we arrange the alkyl groups alphabetically. Then if we just follow the numbers, we can get somethign like 3-methyl-6-ethylnonane and that saves the extra step of arranging alkyl groups alphabetically. it's much easier to follow.

So I assume the extra step of arranging things alphabetically comes with a reason behind it? otherwise doesn't make sense to make things harder?

Comment: There is a thing called "alphanumerical order'. For starters, read this: [Nomenclature of organic compound](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/31709/nomenclature-of-an-organic-compound)

Comment: We have established conventions so that compounds have one unambiguous standard name.